# Change font-color/background-color of the button with JQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, html

I am trying to implement a button in the Home view that should change the his state when clicked, but it is not working for some reason. Can you help me, please?

```
    <button id="adminState" class="btn btn-dark"> 
       Enable Admin State 
    </button> 

    <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function () {
          $('#adminState').click(function () {
             if ($(this).find('button').hasClass("btn btn-dark"))
               $(this).find('button').removeClass("btn btn-dark").addClass("label-danger").text("InActive");
             else
               $(this).find('button').removeClass("label-danger").addClass("label-success").text("Active");
          });
       });
     </script>
```

Comment: That isn't valid HTML syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your HTML:

```
<button type="button" id="adminState" <span class
```

You are missing a ">" before the span tag

EDIT:
Try This in your jquery section:

```
var clicked = true;

$("button").click(function(){
 if(clicked){
     $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
     clicked  = false;
 } else {
     $(this).css('background-color', 'blue');
     clicked  = true;
 }
});
```

Comment: No, it is not this I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

```
     <button id="adminState" onclick="EnableDisableButton();" class="btn 
      btn-dark"> Enable Admin State </button> 

     function EnableDisableButton()
            {
                    $('#adminState').click(function () {
                        if ($(this).hasClass("btn-dark"))
                            $(this).removeClass("btn-dark").addClass("label-
                  danger").text("InActive");
                        else
                            $(this).removeClass("label-
                    danger").addClass("").text("Admin State Enabled");
                    });
                };
```

Again not working on first click